# How to set multiple table columns first and then apply filters in TanStack Table using Reactjs

Tags: reactjs, react-table-v7, tanstack

Hi I am using React Table that is TanStack Table for the topic listing using React Js.

I have searched for it and I find 2 ways of filtering

1. Global search, where you have single field to search all over table
2. Column level filtering, where every column has a text field which we can use to filter

But I just need a custom way, where second case is converted to a FORM with all the column fields and I will will put whatever filter I want and after applying the filter should get applied all over table.

Example:
id, firstname, lastname are the columns, So I will be having a form as below

id: enter id
firstname: enter firstname
lastname: enter last name

(Apply Filter Button)

Once I click on Apply filter button then the filter should get applied.

Please give me a Full Code(Reaactjs) if possible as I am out of Patience now and timeline is hard to get.

Many thanks in advance...

I am able to get the Global filtering and Column level filtering Working nicely.

But the requirement is as explained in the description.